# Revert changes on GitHub secret

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to revert the change I have made on my GitHub secret? I am debugging and found that the tasks are failed when secret is changed, and I happen to forgot the value I was using so I cannot change them back directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, once overwritten the old value can't be retrieved.